# How to trigger an event in input text while typing?

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress

I am using the following code in html:

```
Text 1: <input class="form-control text-right" name="majorhead" id="text1" required="" type="number" /> 
<div class="result_area"></div> 

<button class="my_button" type="button" role="button">Click Me</button>
```

My JS:

```
<script>        
    jQuery(".my_button").click(function () {
        jQuery.get(ajaxurl, {'action': 'sayhello'},
                function (msg) {
                    jQuery(".result_area").html(msg);
                });
    });
</script>
```

For now I am able to achieve my result when I click the button. But I want to achieve the same result while typing(my code will need to check for every keys typed) in the input text.

Comment: how do I select only for id="text1"

Answer (score 3):

Try this:You can bind keyup event handler to text1 and call your function in it.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      jQuery("#text1").on("keyup",function(){  
        if($(this).val()) {
           jQuery.get(ajaxurl,{'action': 'sayhello'}, 
             function (msg) { jQuery(".result_area").html(msg);
           });
        } else { // once value deleted from text1, reset the result
          jQuery(".result_area").html('');
        }
      });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Text 1: <input class="form-control text-right" 
        name="majorhead" id="text1" required="" type="number" /> 
<div class="result_area"></div> 
<button class="my_button" type="button" role="button">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: also input event can be used

Comment: Thanks for your quick and accurate answer

Comment: happy to help you :)

Comment: One more, how can I reset the result if I delete the text in the textbox?

Comment: @LaishramPilot, i have updated my code to reset result if all value deleted

Comment: unfortunately it is not working, meaning now it doesn't trigger the event anymore when I press any key

Comment: @LaishramPilot, it is not probably returning from ajax call or there could be any console log. Can you recreate this on jsfiddle or code snippet as my created code snippet it is going in else part.

Answer (score 2):

use oninput event in text field.

```
<input type="text" oninput="scriptName">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use keyup or keydown event to perform oprations. for example :

```
$(".className").on("keyup",function(){
   //Code goes here
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is HTML

```
<input class="form-control" placeholder="Search Service" id="search_service" name="service" autocomplete="off" value="" type="text">
```

This is JS Code

```
jQuery( "#search_service" ).keyup( function() {
```

var search_ser = jQuery(this).val();

var ajax_url = jQuery('#ajax_url_input').val();

jQuery.ajax({

```
type:'POST',
url: ajax_url,
data: {
    action: 'search_service',
    search_ser: search_ser,
},
beforeSend: function(){
},
success:function(data){

    jQuery("._services_list").html(data);

}
```

});

});

```
Here is my Ajax Function in function.php
```

/* Ajax Function to Search Service. */

function search_service() {

$search_ser = $_POST['search_ser'];

echo $search_ser;

die();

}

add_action('wp_ajax_search_service', 'search_service');

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_search_service', 'search_service');